# Old solution not working for missing Tools.jar while building Portico on Red hat Linux using apache ant

Tags: ant, redhat, tools.jar

I have already done my homework before posting this question. I am trying to build Portico-1.0.2 on Red-Hat Linux 64 bit machine using apache ant. Initially I was setting JAVA_HOME path to jre-1.6.0_31/bin folder but it threw an error that : **Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in jre1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar.**

Then after exploring stackoverflow I found few posts explaining to install jdk and set its folder as the JAVA_HOME path. So I have installed Jdk-1.6.0 in Redhat Linux and after installing jdk I located tools.jar file in it's lib folder. Now when I set the JAVA_HOME path to : /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64, it throws an error : **portico-1.0.2/codebase/build.xml:55: The JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set**

But I have set the JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file as follows :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

I am not sure what to do. Any advice on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly the JDK also contains a JRE, the latter you've set as JAVA_HOME thereby repeating your problem...

The [Red hat docs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Portal_Platform/5.1/html/Installation_Guide/Pre_Requisites-Configuring_Your_Java_Environment.html) describe how to set the JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

hi open the bashrc file in the root directory and add the path to your jdk and you will be good to go..

eg

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_19

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin